# Drupal Commerce - Reference Product in another product

Tags: commerce, entities

I am building a Drupal Commerce based site and now I am facing the following issue.

I have created some T-Shirt Products like,

- T-Shirt (White)
- T-Shirt (Black)
- T-Shirt (Blue)

And also created a product display called "Shirts". In that product display I created a new node "T-Shirt". Since The "size" is an attribute to the product type so I am having a select box to select the color while viewing the "T-Shirt" content.

But the problem comes here. As per my need, if the user selects "Color - White" while viewing 
the product display, we need to add another product "Blue-Jeans" to it. So that means, White Shirt and Blue Jeans will go together in cart if selected.

I am using inline_entity_form to reference products in a Product display (Same as Commerce Kickstart Demo "Tops" product display). How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is bundling of products.

Take a look at [Commerce Product Bundle Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle)

The project page says

> You can define products that consists of other products. They are all
>   combined in one add to cart form. The form works like the core add to
>   cart form with all the fancy selection and ajax magic. So the
>   customers can make their selections as usual. The difference is, that
>   the products from mulitple reference fields were presented on one add
>   to cart form.

Comment: thanks but this module is not working for me giving error https://www.drupal.org/node/2199979. 
Also tried Commerce Product Add-on but this only adds the add-ons price to cart not the whole. Any further ideas? I think I'll try commerce custom products.